# how to identify and replace words in a csv file in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have two CSV files, one contains sentences with abbreviations, the other one is a list of abbreviations and their expansion. I want to identify each abbreviation in the first CSV file and replace it with its expansion. This is how this CSV files look:

sample of first file:

v.p. academic

v.p. finance and administration

v.p. academic and student affairs

v.p. corporate services and external relat.
....

sample of second file:

elect'l. : electrical

vp. : vice president

...

this is my code:

```
import csv
with open('firstFile.csv', 'rb') as sentence, open('secondFile.csv', 'rb')
as word,open('new.csv', 'wb') as out:   
reader = csv.reader(sentence)
reader2 = csv.reader(word)
abbr_list = list(reader2) 
filewriter = csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ') 

result = ''
for row in reader:
    for i in range (0,1453):
        temp = abbr_list[i][0]
        temp1 = abbr_list[i][1]
        if temp in row[0]:
            result = row[0].replace(temp,temp1)
            row[0] = result

    filewriter.writerow(row)
```

however, the result I get is not what I was expecting:

result file:

vice president academic

vice president financiale and administrategytegyyion

vice president academic and student affairs

vice president corporate services and executivecutiveternal relatin

Can someone help me to correct my code?

Comment: The samples that you have described have no commas in them. Are these really CSVs?

Comment: @Negin, it's poor form to [delete questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313493/why-svm-probability-in-r-returns-null) when you get an answer. The problem was likely relevant to other users who are learning `e1071::svm`, and there was a bit of time spent trying to better define the problem and its resolution.

Comment: @ r2evans I didn't get my answer that is why I deleted the question. the question was not well defined and I am not allowed to share my entire code. Therefore, it makes it impossible for others to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your string replacement (`row[0].replace`) is not checking whether it matches an entire word. Thus, it's matching 'strat' and turning 'administration' into 'administrategyion', then changing it again into 'administrategyegyion' with the next replacement, etc.

You can either switch to the `re` module to use regular expressions for string replacement, or you can use spaces as part of the match (eg `row[0].replace(' '+temp+' ',' '+temp1+' ')`) - but be aware that the spaces approach will fail if the match is at the start or end of the string.

Comment: thanks for the help, can you give me an example of how I can use regular expressions (re) for this case?

Comment: Use the `\b` metacharacter to match a word boundary, eg `'\b' + temp + '\b'`. The documentation for the `re` module is at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, you'll probably be interested in the `sub` function.